# document.getElementById() in blazor

Tags: c#, html, dom, text, blazor

I need to change a text of a div, and I only have the id of the div. Without `@bind` (as I only have the id), how can I do that? I searched for a bit and some articles that may or may not be outdated stated that blazor doesn't allow access to DOM elements / API, but even so, I don't an access to the entire DOM element, I only want to be able to change the text inside a div or, if that's not possible, even the `value` property.

Comment: have u tried JSInterop yet?

Comment: How are you generating the *div* and the page containing the *div*.  Some code would help.  In Blazor you manipulate the DOM though components and C#, not via javascript.

Comment: This is what @ref is for - See [ElementReference](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/) - if you're dynamically generating the entire thing, that's not really the Blazor paradigm and you'll have to use js interop as was mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ref** attrubute. [Source page](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/passing-html-element-references/) Example:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
Enter your name
<input @ref=ReferenceToInputControl />

@code
{
  ElementReference ReferenceToInputControl;
  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    if (firstRender)
      await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorUniversity.setFocus", ReferenceToInputControl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try and use Blazor as it was intended. I've only come across a few scenarios where I need to call Javascript with an Id and manipulate the DOM.

If you still NEED to run Javascript then you can invoke the Javascript with a parameter which will be your id.

```
await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("javascriptMethodWithIdParameter", Id);
```

Then use this in your Javascript:

```
window.javascriptMethodWithIdParameter = function(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'This is the id: ' + id;
}
```

Here is my simple sample:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/u6stbg0y

*.NET 6 Example above*

*[ASP.NET Core Blazor JavaScript interoperability (JS interop)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/) official documentation*